# Prevent HTML <progress> from freezing during long DOM update

Tags: html, progress-bar

In my HTML `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` I load a big file using `fetch("foo.br")`. In the `.then()` of the promise I decode the file using Brotli, producing an even bigger array. Then finally in the next `.then()` I go through all the lines of this file and update the DOM based upon their content.

I have an `<progress>Loading...</progress>` progress bar that is supposed to be indicating indeterminate progress, but unfortunately during all the actual loading the progress bar freezes. It doesn't start moving again until after loading has finished.

What do I need to do during my long processing of the really big array in order to allow the UI to "breathe" and the progress bar not to freeze? Do I really have to set timers and process only a few lines at a time?

Or would switching to the `await` pattern help things?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please post a minimal code snippet of what and how you try to achieve within your async JS code

Comment: IIRC, DOM updates don't take place while JavaScript is being executed, and so I'm guessing chaining `.then()` code together would be what you want to address. My best suggestion would be to have the `.then()` code execute a function (passing data from the promise in as necessary), which can allow you to create a potentially necessary *pause* in the code (possibly with `setTimeout`) and allowing the DOM to update.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome at least, calling `setTimeout()` from time to time allows the UI to update and the `<progress>` to unfreeze.

In my case, within the promise `.then()`, I added a restartable line-processing loop inside a function named `processNextLines()`. Within the loop, I checked `performance.now()`, and whenever `breathRateMs` milliseconds (configurable) had passed, I broke out of the loop and called `setTimeout(processNextLines, 1)`.

Thus by configuring `breathRateMs` I could set how often the line-processing logic "yielded" to allow the UI a chance to update. A lower `breathRateMs` allows the work to finish sooner, but doesn't update the UI as often; a higher `breathRateMs` allows the progress bar to update more smoothly, but the line processing takes longer overall to finish.